# Oracle APEX 4.2.2 ADMIN cannot login

Tags: oracle-apex

Oracle 11gR1 EE
Linux RHEL 6.3
APEX 4.2.2
APEX Listener 1.1.4

Just upgraded from 4.1.1 and changed the ADMIN password as part of the post-installation (using apxchpwd.sql). I was able to login once as ADMIN and I changed the setting in APEX to not ask for password reset at login for the user ADMIN.
Now I cannot log in as 'ADMIN' at all and when I use the apxchpwd.sql script again, it does not change the password (no errors during the execution of the script but the 'new' password does not work).
What is going on?!?

Other users can log in btw.

Searching only produces a multitude of possible solutions that include reinstalling from scratch after deleting users FLOWS_030000, APEX_040100, APEX_040000 (to which I say 'you must be kidding!).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your ADMIN account is locked. When trying to log into the INTERNAL workspace, do you get an error message saying "The account is locked."?

If so, find out the security_group_id of your INTERNAL account (usually 10):

```
SELECT workspace_id 
FROM apex_workspaces  
WHERE workspace = 'INTERNAL';
```

Then, log onto sqlplus (SYS as SYSDBA) and type:

```
SQL> alter session set current_schema = APEX_040200;

Session altered.

SQL> begin

    wwv_flow_security.g_security_group_id := 10; --replace your security_group_id accordingly
    wwv_flow_fnd_user_api.UNLOCK_ACCOUNT('ADMIN');
    commit;

end;
/
```

You should now be able to log in with the password you set with apxchpwd.sql